# Fopen can't open audio file

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to send an audio file to my live api from my localhost. When i send the audio file (located on my localhost) to the api, **fopen** is able to read the file but when i use a live url like `https://example.amazonaws.com/patient_file/audio.mp3`, Fopen fails to open it.  What could i be doing wrong below

```
        $audio_file = 'audio.mp3';
        $file_path = 'https://example.amazonaws.com/patient_file' . $audio_file;
        $request = $client->post($apiURL, [
                'multipart' => [
                    [
                    'name' => 'info',
                    'contents' => 'info',
                    ],
                     [
                    'name' => 'file',
                    'contents' => fopen($file_path, 'r'),
                ],
       $response = $request->getBody();
       return $response;
```

**PS** allow_url_fopen is enabled

Comment: @04FS , well i have `allow_url_fopen` enabled .. Thanks but that's not it

Comment: _“Fopen fails to open it”_ - how _exactly_ have you determined that then? You are only passing an open file pointer to some library method here, so how do you figure it is the fopen that failed, and not something else afterwards?

Comment: Try with a URL hosted somewhere else, on a “normal” web server. These cloud hosting services often have restrictions in place against “bot” access, maybe that’s what’s happening here.